# How to apply a binary classifier in Scikit learn when attributes are string (not int or float)

Tags: python, numpy, classification, scikit-learn, svm

I have a list of first and last name of people with a binary language class (speak English or not).

Here is a sample file (I changed the names with dummy values to keep the privacy of people):

```
name1,name2,0
name3,name4,0
name5,name6,1
name7,name2,0
name8,name3,0
name9,name10,1
name11,name5,1
```

I wanted to apply machine learning algorithms such as SVM and Naive Bayes using Scikit learn to evaluate a binary classification task. Since scikit does not let the attributes to be string, I transformed them to integers. The transformed sample file is like this:

```
1,2,0
3,4,0
5,6,1
7,2,0
8,3,0
9,10,1
11,5,1
```

I wanted to ask if SVM and Naive Bayes consider the input value of first and last names as independent values or there is some relation between numbers? in other words, is it important that 5 is greater than 2, or the numbers are just going to be considered as unique values regardless of their arithmetic value.

The reason for this question is that if I order the list by language(i.e. English speakers first) and then replace the names with integers, the algorithm gives me very good results(accuracy and f score above 97%). But if I shuffle the list and then replace names with integers, the results will be poor.

**In general, what is the solution to do a classification using Scikit, when attribute values are strings.**

P.S.1: I tested the same dataset with Weka and I didn't have such a problem because Weka uses arff files and it does necessary conversions itself.

P.S.2: Here is the code that I am using to read the file and apply the algorithm (works fine with no error)

```
#read file into numpy array format
path = "/path/to/csv/file/BinaryClassification.csv"
import numpy as np
lstAttributes = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',')[:,0:2]
lstLabels = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',')[:,2:3]
tempArr = []
for v in lstLabels:
    tempArr.append(float(v))
from numpy import array
lstLabels = array(tempArr)

#trains and test algorithms (uses whole data as training and test set)
from sklearn import naive_bayes
classifier = naive_bayes.GaussianNB()
model = classifier.fit(lstAttributes, lstLabels)
prediction = model.predict(lstAttributes)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print confusion_matrix(lstLabels, prediction)

#Use 5 fold cross validation to evaluate the algorithms
from sklearn import cross_validation
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier, lstAttributes, lstLabels, cv=5, scoring='f1')
print("cross validation: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

Comment: In SVM, input is cardinal (so order matters). If your input is nominal, I would use induction rules (for instance, a decision tree) or naive bayes should be fine as well. You can use SVMs, but you have to binarize them: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52915/how-to-deal-with-an-svm-with-categorical-attributes (which in your case sounds awfully expensive)

Answer (score 2):

**In general**, you have to know what the strings mean in order to convert them to numeric feature values, and you also have to consider which learning algorithm the result goes into. In this case, a one-hot encoding is probably the best thing to try first. [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) implements that. The result will be a sparse matrix of indicator variables, so you'd better switch from `GaussianNB` to `BernoulliNB` (not that `GaussianNB` makes sense for your current encoding).